# JSON not being parse correctly

Tags: java

I am using Spark (for Java) to create a simple checkers game for the web (this is for a course). I have been stuck on this problem for a bit, and my research on this problem has not brought me anything useful.

In this project, we use Spark (Spark + Jetty), FreeMarker, JS, HTML, CSS, etc. The entire code-base for JS was given to us, and works as intended if we do it right. We are not supposed to touch the JS.

Right now, I'm trying to create a a POST method for when the user clicks the resign button in a game. If that is the case, the JS should send a POST to '/resignGame', which I have created a Route for:

```
@Override
public Object handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> vm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    vm.put("title", "Welcome!");

    final Session session = request.session();
    boolean sessionHasUser = session.attribute("username") != null;
    if (!sessionHasUser) {
        request.session().attribute("errorMessage", "You tried to resign a game, but you are not logged in.");
        response.redirect("/");
        return null;
    }

    final String username = (String) session.attribute("username");
    if (gameLobby.isPlayerInGame(username)) {
        Game game = gameLobby.getGame(username);
        gameLobby.endGame(game);

        Message message = new Message("Successfully resigned.", Message.Type.info);
        System.out.printf("Converting object to JSON: %s\n", message.toString());
        String json = gson.toJson(message);
        System.out.printf("JSON: %s\n", json);
        System.out.printf("Setting body to %s\n", json);

        response.body(json);
        response.redirect("/");
        return null;
    } else {
        request.session().attribute("errorMessage", "You tried to resign a game, but you are not in a game.");
        response.redirect("/");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Pretty much, what is happening here is I check for a user in the session. After that, if the user is in the session, I get the username and check if the player is in a game. If they are in a game, I end the game. Here is where I'm getting the error. Here are the instructions for the /resignGame protocol:

[resignGame Protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ6KM.png)

To sum it up, we put a Message object (in JSON) in the response body, with the 'type' being 'info' if the resign was successful and 'error' if the resign was not successful. For testing, I'm assuming that the resign was sucessfull and the user should be brought back to the home screen. So, as you can see in the code, I create the message object, I print out some information to make sure it converted to JSON correctly, then put it in the response body and redirect it back to home.

However, this does not work. Here is the console output:

```
Converting object to JSON: com.webcheckers.model.Message@4e873b6c
JSON: {"text":"Successfully resigned.","type":"info"}
Setting body to {"text":"Successfully resigned.","type":"info"}
```

But here is the error I receive:

[popup error](https://i.gyazo.com/3d58b8fe15d3e74cc25748a43215b0ea.png)

This error makes it seem like the wrong kind of thing is being sent into the JS. I'm not really sure what is going on here, so I'm posting for help. I'm able to provide any information that you ask of.

If anyone has experience with Spark and this kind of stuff, please respond!

EDIT: Instead of redirecting, I added a Spark.halt() which fixed the 302 error that was being seen, but a new popup is now being sent to me:

[popup again](https://i.gyazo.com/3d58b8fe15d3e74cc25748a43215b0ea.png)

It says "Unknown error (status=200) error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

So now it seems like the end of the input is messing up instead of the beginning. BUT, the console output is still the same (as seen obove when converting the object to json and then sending the json)

Console view:

[enter image description here](https://i.gyazo.com/22cb9b5777634711f35cf6fa70e8f0ff.png)

Comment: The 'popup error' image you've linked appears to be blank.

Comment: If you supply a body with a 302 (redirect), most browsers will ignore the body. Maybe get rid of the  `response.redirect("/");` call before `response.body(json);`

Comment: @MarkMucha I fixed the popup error link (and also added the new one) with text explaining what it said. I replaced the redirect with a Spark.halt() which fixed the 302 error and added the console view I have! Thanks for the tip!